# OCR (Optical Character Recognition) for on-screen text

Tags: c#, automation, automated-tests, ocr

I'm trying to create a piece of software that automate the PC by capturing the screenshot, then OCR (Optical Character Recognition) it looking for a particular button to click (for example). I've got the mouse and keyboard control part, but now, I needed an OCR to process the screenshot. What I discovered is that Tesseract OCR does not seems to work very well with on-screen text. The text is either too small, or that some of text seems to be connected, like for example K and X. How should I go about this?

p/s: this is for an automated test program.

Comment: Could you just bump up the text size and tweak the font on the test machine?

Comment: What exactly do you want to test?

If it's a simple test program you can query Windows using SendMessage and GetWndText to search for the buttons and controls you like.

Why go to the hussle of an OCR?

Comment: I can bump up the text size, but some of the font inside the application can't be bumped up without modifying code.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142743/what-software-would-you-recommend-for-image-enhancement-prior-to-ocr-optical-cha) on image enhancement prior to OCR.
Otherwise this question is pretty similar to ["OCR for .NET"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870280/ocr-for-net).

If you are feeling really bold you can always whip up a simple Perceptron or Neural Network based approach :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this really fits the bill for you, but some of the better OCR that I have seen in automation is done by Tevron's [CitraTest](http://www.tevron.com/default.asp).  It has a library of fonts included and if a fontset is not present, they will create a new one based on your submissions.  Nagative factors with this tool would be cost and the usual issues related to variable screen resolution.